# Saving Email via RDOMail.SaveAs method takes too long when using non-cached outlook

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, office-addins, outlook-redemption

I am using RDOMail.SaveAs() method to save an email in RFC822 (olRFC822_Redemption) format, while the Cached Exchange Mode is turned off in Outlook, the method takes too long (~5-10sec) to complete.

It also happens with emails that are older than the value set in the Exchange Account Settings if using Cached Exchange Mode.

I also tried with small emails, hence the problem is not the size of an email. Also could not find any issue related to this behaviour on the web.

What is the reason it takes too long to finish, while the Outlook opens the mail quickly?
What can I do to increase the performance of saving the mail in RFC822 format?

There is no problem saving an email that is already cached/downloaded.

Im using:

- Redemption v5.27
- Windows 10 x64
- MS 365 Outlook 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148) 64-bit

I have made some benchmark to illustrate the problem.

Benchmark results for an email that is **not cached**:

|  | #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 | #5 | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| olTXT | 1233.9179 ms | 1605.0744 ms | 1067.1984 ms | 1087.7771 ms | 1036.7383 ms | 1206.14122 ms |
| olRTF | 1162.7081 ms | 1043.8742 ms | 1131.8348 ms | 1038.5895 ms | 1045.629 ms | 1084.52712 ms |
| olTemplate | 283.9979 ms | 607.3346 ms | 231.3278 ms | 253.0763 ms | 220.7174 ms | 319.2908 ms |
| olMSG | 193.0037 ms | 192.1193 ms | 175.8402 ms | 193.0315 ms | 183.844 ms | 187.56774 ms |
| olMSGUnicode | 238.9995 ms | 238.1113 ms | 217.5729 ms | 233.68 ms | 229.1856 ms | 231.50986 ms |
| olHTML | 2176.2175 ms | 2160.0654 ms | 1801.6547 ms | 1786.0087 ms | 1844.9965 ms | 1953.78856 ms |
| olMHTML | 2040.2919 ms | 2037.1368 ms | 2103.5237 ms | 2094.5258 ms | 2060.9724 ms | 2067.29012 ms |
| olMHTMLWithAddresses | 1662.0322 ms | 1716.8635 ms | 2458.9654 ms | 2093.9039 ms | 1714.7971 ms | 1929.31242 ms |
| olRFC822 | 4909.5307 ms | 4686.1674 ms | 4876.3511 ms | 4659.7755 ms | 4939.6519 ms | 4814.29532 ms |
| olRFC822_Redemption | 4556.5926 ms | 4661.7288 ms | 4836.586 ms | 4617.6806 ms | 4973.5898 ms | 4729.23556 ms |
| olRFC822_Tnef | 4941.2885 ms | 6016.8583 ms | 5222.8734 ms | 5148.6418 ms | 4840.2205 ms | 5233.9765 ms |

Benchmark results for an email that is **cached (or pre downloaded)**:

|  | #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 | #5 | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| olTXT | 37.0018 ms | 1.0009 ms | 1.0015 ms | 0.999 ms | 1 ms | 8.20064 ms |
| olRTF | 15.9999 ms | 6.9991 ms | 9.0003 ms | 19.0016 ms | 6.0024 ms | 11.40066 ms |
| olTemplate | 17.0064 ms | 17.9998 ms | 19.9996 ms | 23 ms | 17.9962 ms | 19.2004 ms |
| olMSG | 18.0006 ms | 17.9988 ms | 20.0005 ms | 18.0002 ms | 17.0016 ms | 18.20034 ms |
| olMSGUnicode | 21.9966 ms | 18.0003 ms | 19.0119 ms | 16.9994 ms | 19.0122 ms | 19.00408 ms |
| olHTML | 2.0028 ms | 2.0001 ms | 2.0023 ms | 1.0014 ms | 1.9973 ms | 1.80078 ms |
| olMHTML | 2 ms | 1.9992 ms | 2.0006 ms | 1.9987 ms | 2.0029 ms | 2.00028 ms |
| olMHTMLWithAddresses | 3.0004 ms | 2.9999 ms | 2.9999 ms | 2.0005 ms | 2.0024 ms | 2.60062 ms |
| olRFC822 | 871.1101 ms | 482.9009 ms | 475.6052 ms | 525.0308 ms | 475.5305 ms | 566.0355 ms |
| olRFC822_Redemption | 3.9994 ms | 2.9985 ms | 3.0021 ms | 4.0013 ms | 2.9988 ms | 3.40002 ms |
| olRFC822_Tnef | 8.0003 ms | 7.0002 ms | 8.0017 ms | 7.9987 ms | 8.9999 ms | 8.00016 ms |

Comment: Did you try to use the Outlook object model for saving the same emails that take too much time? Is there any difference?

Comment: Do you get any delays when saving messages in any other file format?

Comment: I have made some benchmark and edited the original post with the results.

Comment: This is to be expected - as much as Redemption tries to optimize property retrieval (so that they are retrieved in batches rather than one at a time), each access means a round trip to the remote server. Which is as expensive as it gets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That actually sounds normal. In real life when doing that manually it may take like an eternity. I'd recommend switching to using the cached mode in Outlook, that's really a best practice and how the architecture is designed to run optimally.

Comment: I am aware that using cached mode would work better, and would not consume much storage, but some of our customers are using outlook in terminal server where cached mode cannot be used. Hence I would like to get a solution for this problem, because it is a crucial part of the product.